# How can detect a folder?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My folder Name: "20170623154519_test.pdf"
I used this code:

```
  Dim isDir = (File.GetAttributes(strOutput) & FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory
```

But it working not correct.

How can detect a folder?
Thanks all.

Comment: Why not use `Directory.GetDirectories` and compare the names with the one you want. and a folder shouldn't have `.pdf` at the end otherwise it should be a file.

Comment: I can't understand your question at all. You've got a folder with `.pdf` extension?

Comment: @Pikoh: yes. that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the and operation. What you need is a bitwise and [(`And`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator) in VB.net, not [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator) (string concatenation):

```
Dim isDir = (File.GetAttributes(strOutput) And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim isDir = System.IO.Directory.Exists("20170623154519_test.pdf")
```

That code will check for a folder named "20170623154519_test.pdf"